# How to get row count of each select statement in proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

```
Create procedure procedurename
AS
Begin

    Select * from Table  

End

Exec Procedurename

Select @@rowcount
```

Above query will show number of rows returned by proc. What if I have multiple select statements and I want row count of each select statement in proc.

Note : I can't modify proc.

Is there any possibility ?

Sample proc :

```
Create procedure procedurename
AS
Begin

    Select * from Table1 
    Select * from Table2   

End

Exec Procedurename
```

Comment: How `Select * from Table1` return count?

Comment: That is my doubt. Is there any possibility to get it

Comment: If you can't modify the proc then you're stuck really. The question is what are you trying to achieve then perhaps someone can then come up with options

Comment: Then try getting the count in your front end. Are you using .NET?